# head.js and jQuery issues in Chrome / Firefox 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, document, head.js

So the page is rendered like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>

   head.js("js/jquery.js",
           "js/jquery.autocomplete.js");

  </script>
</head>

<body>

  ...
  stuff here
  ...

  <script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){  // fail...

      $('body').removeClass('no-jquery');
      // ...

    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The scripts seem to load and all in Opera, but in Firefox 5 and Chrome (don't know the version because it changes every day) I get a error:

```
jQuery is not defined
[Break On This Error] jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

So I guess jquery is not really loaded by head.js in these browsers? Or I'm doing something wrong?

---

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/LDUUd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching to `head.ready()` instead of `jQuery.ready()`.

Comment: Or load your own script not inline but as a separate file via HeadJS as well.

Comment: then I get `head(document) is undefined...`

Comment: Something's off, can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Ohh, you don't need `head(document)`. Just say `head.ready(function() {...`; See here: http://headjs.com/#usage

Comment: I got it working finally, but only works if I use jQuery instead of $ in that head.ready function. If I use `$` I get a error: `$ is not a function`

Comment: If you really want to use `$`, try this: `head.ready((function($){ /* code goes here */ }(jQuery)));`

Comment: This works for me (even without the function wrapper): http://jsfiddle.net/MRVHU/

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [example of it working](http://jsbin.com/etuled) - is this what you have?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `head.js()` without

```
<!-- assuming it's in the same directory as the page -->
<script src="head.min.js"></script>
```

first.

Comment: I have that too, just forgot to mention it in the code above.. (`head.load.min.js`)